# How to get csrf token in Jmeter to use for log-in

Tags: authentication, jmeter, csrf

I'm trying a log-in scenario for a page, but it's getting an error because of the csrf_token and other dynamic parameters that are being generated every time I run the test. How do I get these csrf_token and these parameters to use in my test?

Please see image below.

[Request Header parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2FC0.png)

[Jmeter Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIaV0.jpg)

[Error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebYVY.jpg)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract it from the previous response using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and replace the recorded value with the variable.

The process is known as ["correlation"](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) and there is a lot of information on the topic over the web, for example the article [What is CSRF & How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-csrf-load-testing) would be a good starting point.